# No accepted shares on cgminer (sync issue ?)

Tags: blockchain, cgminer

I don't really understand how cgminer works.
I try to mine using cgminer + cgwatcher on a BtcGuild pool but even after 1 hour mining I don't have any accepted or share block. What I don't understand is how cgminer sync with the current blockchain data??? Blockchain data is about 11Go. Should I find blk0001.DAT file in cgminer folder or Roaming folder?
Is it possible to keep miner tool (on a USB key) and keep data on the same USB key.

Thanx

Answer (score 1):

CGMiner does not need to sync with the blockchain, the pool does. The pool keeps a copy of the blockchain and only sends you the block that is currently being mined. If you don't see any share on BTCGuild's website, you should check that your miner's username and password are correct (they can be different from your main username and password). If you see shares, but they are constantly rejected, then you have a connection problem between you and the pool server. If this is the case, try changing to another pool.

Comment: I do not have rejected block. I'm using a ATI w600. I don't know its hash rate power. Hashing rate is always equal to 0. Do I need to have an accepted block to know my hashing power. If my username is not correct should I have a special message? I don't know if I can send a log file to be more clear?

Comment: Yes, you can post your log file here. If the pool says you have a hashrate of 0, then they are not receiving any mined shares. If your CGMiner shows a hashrate of 0, then it means you are not mining (problem with GPU drivers, using a new version of CGMiner not designed for GPU mining, etc.)

Comment: I was using latest cgminer version (3.8.x), I downgraded to 3.7.2 to get GPU support. I installed ATI SDK to get OpenCL support (%system32%/OpenCL.dll is present). But when I run tests with cgwatcher I read OpenCL=-1 and so cgminer tells me that no GPU is usable... Are all ATI gpu supported for mining?